# If $f(1-x)-2f(x) = 1-x$, then solve for $f(\sin x-\cos x) = \frac{\sqrt{2}-4}{6}.$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

> If $f(1-x)-2f(x) = 1-x$, then solve for 
>   $$f(\sin x-\cos x) = \frac{\sqrt{2}-4}{6}.$$

How do I do this? I'm a bit confused with notations function notations; what's the difference between $f(x), f(x+2), f(2x)$? etc...

For example if $f(x)= x+1$, then $f(x+1)= (x+1)+1$, right? $f(x)$ is the base function where $x$ is the input; $f(x+1)$ is the same function machine but with $x+1$ as the input.

Could you please elaborate... :D

sorry for the bad phrasing...

Comment: For everyone's convenience (yours too), please learn to format on this site. That way you don't have to use some web service to make images for you. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3):

(1)$$f(1-\color{red}{x})-2f(\color{red}{x})=1-\color{red}{x} $$ 
$$f(1-\color{red}{(1-x)})-2f(\color{red}{1-x})=1-\color{red}{(1-x)}$$
Then

(2) $$f(x)-2f(1-x)=x $$ 
$(2 \cdot (1)+(2)) \Rightarrow$
$$-3f(x)=2-x$$
$$f(x)=\frac{x-2}{3}$$

Hince, $$f(\sin x-\cos x) =\frac{\sin x-\cos x-2}{3}= \frac{\sqrt{2}-4}{6}.$$
$$\sin x - \cos x=\frac {\sqrt2}2$$

Comment: thanks , so the thing is to find a certain input for which the expression simplifies ?

Comment: @therue Yup. And that's in my answer

Answer (score 2):

$$2f(1-x)-f(x)=1-x$$$$\implies2f(x)-f(1-x)=x\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (\text{Put $1-x$ in place of $x$})$$$$\implies f(x)={x-2\over 3}$$
Now $${\sin (x)-\cos(x)-2\over 3}={\sqrt2-4\over 6}\implies \sin(x)-\cos(x)-2={1\over \sqrt2}-2$$$$\implies \sin(x)-\cos(x)={1\over \sqrt2}$$$$\implies \sin(x-\pi/4)=1/2=\sin(2n\pi+\pi/6)$$
$$\implies x=2n\pi-\pi/12$$